# What is Happening to my Sieve of Eratosthenes Program?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to solve a challenge question of summing all primes under 2 million. Knowing full well a naive approach would take too long, I decided to implement The Sieve of Eratosthenes with a counter to record the sum. It works for up to 512500 after which I receive this error:

[image]

Is the input size just too big for code to handle? If that's the case, how can I improve my code to avoid this error. If that's not possible, what is a better algorithm to implement for these purposes?

Here is my header code:

```
#ifndef NUMBERSIEVE_H
#define NUMBERSIEVE_H


class NumberSieve
{
    public:
        NumberSieve();
        virtual ~NumberSieve();
        int EratosthenesSieve(int num);
    private:
        void SetSieve(int nums[],int Size);
        int current_prime;
        int current_prime_address;
        void updateSieve(int nums[],int Size,int start);
        bool updateCurrentPrime(int nums[],int Size,int start);
        bool notComplete;
        void printSieve(int nums[],int Size);
        int primeSum;
};

#endif // NUMBERSIEVE_H
```

Here is my implementation file:

```
#include "NumberSieve.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
NumberSieve::NumberSieve()
{
    //ctor
}

NumberSieve::~NumberSieve()
{
    //dtor
}
void NumberSieve::SetSieve(int nums[],int Size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<Size;i++)
    {
        nums[i]=(i+1);
    }
    nums[0]=0;//Sets the first composite number 1 to 0. We use 0 as an analogy for "crossing out numbers in the Sieve".
}
void NumberSieve::updateSieve(int nums[],int Size,int start)
{
    int CURRENT_PRIME=nums[start];
    for(int i=start;i<Size;i++)
    {
        if(nums[i]%CURRENT_PRIME==0)
        {
            nums[i]=0;
        }
    }
    nums[start]=CURRENT_PRIME;
}
bool NumberSieve::updateCurrentPrime(int nums[],int Size,int start)
{
    for(int i=start+1;i<Size;i++)
    {
        if(nums[i]!=0)
        {
            primeSum+=nums[i];
            current_prime=nums[i];
            current_prime_address=i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
void NumberSieve::printSieve(int nums[],int Size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<Size;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<nums[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
int NumberSieve::EratosthenesSieve(int num)
{
    int Eratosthenes[num];
    int primeSum=0;
    SetSieve(Eratosthenes,num);
    current_prime=2;
    primeSum+=2;
    current_prime_address=1;
    updateSieve(Eratosthenes,num,current_prime_address);
    notComplete=updateCurrentPrime(Eratosthenes,num,current_prime_address);
    while(notComplete)
    {
        updateSieve(Eratosthenes,num,current_prime_address);
        notComplete=updateCurrentPrime(Eratosthenes,num,current_prime_address);
    }
    return primeSum;
}
```

Comment: Well, I'd recommend clicking the debug option, and windup the stack trace.

Comment: About the `updateSieve` function - this version manages to throw away performance gains you expect to get by using a sieve.  The loop should not iterate through every single number and check each one for congruency with a slow modulo operation -- each iteration should skip an index count equal to the current prime and just set that to zero.  Something like: `for(int i=start; i<Size; i += CURRENT_PRIME){nums[i]=0;}`  Of course, you could also change start to be `start + CURRENT_PRIME` so you don't have to go back and unzero it after the loop.  I have no idea about the cause of the crash.

Comment: Please tell us what exception do you get?

Comment: Also once you find a prime, you can square it, as 2*p, 3*p .. < p * p, are already removed from the sieve by elimination of previous prime factors.  eg) for 5, 2*5, 3*5 & 4*5 should already be remov-ed so 5*5, 7*5, 9*5 and so on are ones that need removing.  Actually finding primes < 2million, should only take a few seconds in C++ at most, so there's not much need for efficiency, to solve the summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is stackoverflow, because of this:

```
int Eratosthenes[num];
```

Instead try getting it from the free store:

```
int* Eratosthenes = new int[num]
```

Update the rest of the code accordingly

If you are not comfortable with pointers, a vector might be another option.

Comment: With C++ & Codeblocks; I found using a char vector was fine for the sieve, but a bit vector was a little faster as you scan over less memory.